# TypeScript in Visual Studio 2013 Ambient Declarations

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, typescript

New to TypeScript, please let me know if something is left out ... Okay here is my complete code:

```
/// <reference path="typings/knockout.d.ts" />

declare var ko: any; 

module test {

    var name = ko.observable('John Dude');
    var id = ko.observable(1);
    var guy = {
        id: id,
        fullName: name
    };

    var value: string = guy.fullName();
    console.log(value);
}
```

The problem is ... I get this message, something about this line

> declare var ko: any;

and here is the actual message

[image: TypeScript declaration error ...]

I have no idea how to fix it, tried pretty much everything! ... no idea why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've included `knockout.d.ts`, you no longer need the line `declare var ko: any;` as the .d.ts file has already defined the shape of `ko` for you. The compiler is warning you that you're declaring `ko` with two different types (`any`, and the more complex type defined in the .d.ts file).

Simply remove that line of code.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. When I do remove it like you mention I get the following in Google chrome dev tools. [Uncaught ReferenceError: ko is not defined] What do I do now?

Comment: You need to include knockout.js in a script tag (above the script tag that includes your .js file) in your HTML

Comment: Also there was some other library that was interfering, but after this, "you no longer need the line declare var ko: any;" was able to troubleshoot it and fixed it. Thank you.